# Java - atomically delete a (non-empty) directory

Tags: java, concurrency, io

In a Java application, is there a way to atomically (with regards to other running processes) delete a non-empty directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OS (Windows, Unix) doesn't support this operation, but what you can do is rename the directory or even move it away and then delete it later.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *typical* operating systems don't support this.  It is possible that *some* operating system *could* support this.  But you are right.  Since *typical* operating systems don't support this, Java can't either.